# Python: The system cannot find the path specified: 'data'

Tags: python, operating-system, deep-learning, spyder

I'm building a CNN using Python
I have a folder of pictures for classification stored in D//Files directory
however an exception keeps poping

code:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.preprocessing.image import  img_to_array



import numpy as np

# Image manipulations and arranging data
import os
from PIL import Image
import theano
theano.config.optimizer="None"

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
os.chdir("D:/File");

# input image dimensions
m,n = 50,50

path1="input";
path2="data";

classes=os.listdir(path2)

x=[]
y=[]
for fol in classes:
    print (fol)
    imgfiles=os.listdir(path2+'\\'+fol);
    for img in imgfiles:
        im=Image.open(path2+'\\'+fol+'\\'+img);
        im=im.convert(mode='RGB')
        imrs=im.resize((m,n))
        imrs=img_to_array(imrs)/255;
        imrs=imrs.transpose(2,0,1);
        imrs=imrs.reshape(3,m,n);
        x.append(imrs)
        y.append(fol)

x=np.array(x);
y=np.array(y);

batch_size=32
nb_classes=len(classes)
nb_epoch=20
nb_filters=32
nb_pool=2
nb_conv=3

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=4)

uniques, id_train=np.unique(y_train,return_inverse=True)
Y_train=np_utils.to_categorical(id_train,nb_classes)
uniques, id_test=np.unique(y_test,return_inverse=True)
Y_test=np_utils.to_categorical(id_test,nb_classes)

model= Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters,nb_conv,nb_conv,border_mode='same',input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'));
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters,nb_conv,nb_conv));
model.add(Activation('relu'));
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool,nb_pool)));
model.add(Dropout(0.5));
model.add(Flatten());
model.add(Dense(128));
model.add(Dropout(0.5));
model.add(Dense(nb_classes));
model.add(Activation('softmax'));
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adadelta',metrics=['accuracy'])


nb_epoch=5;
batch_size=5;
model.fit(x_train,Y_train,batch_size=batch_size,nb_epoch=nb_epoch,verbose=1,validation_data=(x_test, Y_test))


files=os.listdir(path1);
img=files[0] 
im = Image.open(path1 + '\\'+img);
imrs = im.resize((m,n))
imrs=img_to_array(imrs)/255;
imrs=imrs.transpose(2,0,1);
imrs=imrs.reshape(3,m,n);

x=[]
x.append(imrs)
x=np.array(x);
predictions = model.predict(x)
```

however this script does not run and gives me this in the consolem it seems that the path specified is not recognised (I'm using Windows with Python 3.6 and Spyder environment)

```
runfile('C:/Users/Monirah/.spyder-py3/semi1.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/Monirah/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-13-144f8465de97>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Monirah/.spyder-py3/semi1.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/Monirah/.spyder-py3')

File "C:\Users\Monirah\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Monirah\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Monirah/.spyder-py3/semi1.py", line 26, in <module>
classes=os.listdir(path2)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 
'data'
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to look into. Are you sure that all of it is really relevant with regards to the given problem?

Comment: Can you do a `print os.path.exists(path2)` before the  `classes=os.listdir(path2)` line?

Comment: print os.path.exists(path2)  returns false

Comment: Does this "data" folder even exist in specified location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use debug or start with 
 printing out all the paths you use in your program and check that they are valid.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use "\" in windows for paths Ex: c:\mydir
2. After `os.chdir("D:/File");`, do `print os.getcwd()` & check whether current directory is same as the path used in `os.chdir()`
3. Now check whether `print os.path.exists(path2)` exists in your current directory.

Note: Always use `os.path.join()` for file path manipulations. This works well irrespective of the underlying OS.